# Convert base64 string image from upload to SVG without writing file

Tags: php, svg, command-line, imagick

I have canvas generated jpg in base64 string uploaded by ajax to php. I have the following working code to do the data:image/jpeg;base64 to svg conversion.

```
//Uploaded is a string start from data:image/jpeg;base64,...(not a .jpg)
$b64 = (isset($_POST['img']) ? $_POST['img'] : null);
if($b64){
    $b64= str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $b64);
    $b64= str_replace(' ', '+', $b64);
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->readImageBlob(base64_decode($b64));
    $im->trimImage(2000);
    $im->setImageFormat( "ppm" );
    $im->writeImage( "out.ppm" );   
    $cmd = exec("potrace out.ppm -s -o out.svg 2>&1", $output, $e);
}
```

However, I found that writing file is a very slow process and make my file system messy. I want to eliminate the writing process by piping the command so that no writing file is needed, but I am not familiar with command line.

Imagick limits the input string up to 5000 characters, so I cannot do like this as it fails once b64 is too long.

```
exec("convert inline:".$b64." ppm:- | potrace -s -o out.svg");
```

So,I tried to do the following to wrap the string to a text file but it fails as the content is different and without the "data:image/jpeg;base64" at the beginning. I don't want to write a text file everytime too.

```
if(strlen($b64)> 4000){
    $arr = str_split($b64, 4000);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $a) {
        $test = exec("echo ".$a." >> out.b64 2>&1", $output, $e);
    }
}
```

Q1: Any chance I can wrap the b64 string into a temp text file as an input to imagick?

Q2: I want to echo back the svg xml instead of download it as a file. And again, this writes a new file although this is faster. I hope there is a method not  outputing as a file but as a variable or object like thing in php.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.,

```
        $base64_str = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $b64);
        $base64_str = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_str);
        $decoded = base64_decode($base64_str);
        $targetPath ="../your target path/";
        $png_url ="../your target path/"."product-".strtotime('now').".png";
        $image_name ="product-".strtotime('now').".png";            
        $result = file_put_contents($png_url, $decoded);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to pass the long base64 string into command line app like imagick as an argument instead of saving base64 to png file with random name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to respond to such an old question, but I'm a little confused, why are you trying to convert a base64 encoded JPG (a [raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) image format) to SVG (a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) image format)?

That won't work, and best case scenario, the SVG will just contain a reference to the original JPG. Is that what you were looking to do?

Comment: The code above includes potrace which is a library to convert raster image to vector image.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you are looking for this:

to get base64_encode of an uploaded image (tmp image):

```
$filename  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
$data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$encoded_img = base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The uploaded data is a URI base64 string generated by Canvas method toDataURL(), not a .jpg file.